# Passing simple list of strings to view in MVC without using model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to create a view that lists erorrs occured, while executing some action in a controller. I know how to create views while using a model, but can it be done  without using a model? Just by passing simple list of strings?

I've created an action for the view with errors:

```
    public ActionResult ListOfErrors(List<string> listOfErrors)
    {
        return View(listOfErrors);
    }
```

And a view for this action:

```
@model List<string>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Error
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.ToString();
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I do it like this I just get ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.String]; ```. What should I change?

Comment: include the namespace int model declaration @model System.Collections.Generic.List<System.string>

Comment: [Passing string as model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967178/7703386), should work with any type really.

Comment: @Wubbler I tried it but I'm not sure what to add in the view, I have `@model List<string>` but if I run the code it still gives me only one record: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String];

Comment: That is peculiar indeed, I made a sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xu1l8P) and everything works in there as expected. Calling `ToString()` on list of strings is unnecessary but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Wubbler, ok, the problem was in passed argument to the ActionResult. My route values weren't correct in a "RedirectToAction" function. Now it works, thanks :)

Comment: What are you submitting to the controller (i.e. what is in `List<string> listOfErrors`)?

Comment: `foreach`ing a `list<String>` means that `item` is a `string`, so there is no need to `ToString()` it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable into ViewBag with your desired name (mine is ErrorList) in your action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ErrorList = new List<string>() { "Error 1", "Error 2" };
    return View();
}
```

Then you can user this object in your view and do your magic:

```
<ul>
@foreach (string error in (List<string>)ViewBag.ErrorList)
{
    <li>error</li>
}</ul>
```